# Populate a multi dimensional array using mySQL query involving relational tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, relational-database

This might be fairly simple for the experts but I need help as a newbie.  I have the following three tables which has items & attachments.  I would like to have these data populated into a multi dimensional array as given in the result section below (in JSON format).

```
Tables - columns

items
- itemID
- itemTitle
- catID

attachments
- attachmentID
- itemID
- attachmentFilename
```

Considering there are two items in the database with the first item related to 2 attachments and the second item related to 3 attachments, this is how I would like to see the result:

```
{
    "items": [{
        "item": {
            "itemID": "1",
            "itemTitle": "The first item",
            "attachments": [{
                "attachment": {
                    "attachmentFilename": "The First attachment.att",
                    "attachmentID": "1"
                },
                "attachment": {
                    "attachmentFilename": "The Second attachment.att",
                    "attachmentID": "2"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "itemID": "2",
            "itemTitle": "The Second item",
            "attachments": [{
                "attachment": {
                    "attachmentFilename": "The Third attachment.att",
                    "attachmentID": "3"
                },
                "attachment": {
                    "attachmentFilename": "The Fourth attachment.att",
                    "attachmentID": "4"
                },
                "attachment": {
                    "attachmentFilename": "The Fifth attachment.att",
                    "attachmentID": "5"
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

I would like to know how I can code in php such that I will get the above result.  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: My suggestion for you is try some code by your own. If there's any problem then seek help. If you tried something then post the code and people may help you.

Comment: @phazorRise, I had tried coding as follows but I cant figure out how to separate the related tables after I get the required data from the database.  Please see below.

Comment: $query = 
 "SELECT
 `items`.`id` AS `itemID`,
 `items`.`title` AS `itemTitle`,
 `attachments`.`filename` AS `attachmentFilename`,
 `attachments`.`id` AS `attachmentID` 

 FROM `items` 

 INNER JOIN  `attachments`
 ON `items`.`id`=`attachments`.`itemID`";

    $result = mysql_query($query,$link) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

    /* create one master array of the records */
    $items = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $items[] = array('item'=>$item);
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you really get the data to insert in JSON, take a look at [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode).
Once your data has been stored in a variable you can loop through it with [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) and for each loop insert the data appropriately.